# Sending mail through SendGrid on Java Play application fails

Tags: java, heroku, playframework, smtp, sendgrid

I'm trying to send a simple test email through SendGrid from my Java Play 2.10 application. I'm using the play-plugins-mailer to send the email and have a free (heroku) SendGrid account. This is everything I've done so far for:

- Added the play-plugins-mailer dependency to my Build.scala
- Added the CommonsMailerPlugin to my play.plugins file
- Added the following code in my controller to send an email:

  ```
  MailerAPI mail = play.Play.application().plugin(MailerPlugin.class).email();
  mail.setSubject("test subject");
  mail.addRecipient("test@gmail.com");
  mail.addFrom("testapp@heroku.com");
  mail.send("some text");
  ```
- Added the following in my application.conf:

  ```
  smtp.host="smtp.sendgrid.net"
  smtp.user="[my-sendgrid-user]"
  smtp.pass="[my-sendgrid-pass]"
  smtp.port="587"
  smtp.channel=plain
  ```

I'm pretty sure the Mailer is working fine, it just seems to be a SendGrid configuration issue. When this code gets executed I get this error:

**[RuntimeException: org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.sendgrid.net:587]**

I've tried running this on my local machine as well as on heroku where I've added the SendGrid plugin to my app.

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at this thread?  [Send mail in Heroku using SendGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8196521/send-mail-in-heroku-using-sendgrid)

Also, you might what to try the Typesafe mail plug as described in this tutorial:

> http://blog.flurdy.com/2012/05/send-email-via-sendgrid-on-heroku-using.html

Comment: Yes tried that thread, as you can see in my error message I already changed the port to 587 but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the Java API given here at official SendGrid-java Jithub project.

[Official Send-Grid Java API](https://github.com/sendgrid/smtpapi-java)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
smtp.ssl=true
```

That [worked for me](https://github.com/jamesward/happytrails/blob/play2_java).